# JUnit Test if XML Document is sorted on arbitrary column

Tags: xml, xpath, junit, xunit, xmlunit

Given an xml document like

```
<root>
  <row>
    <a>2</a>
    <b>1</b>
    <c>8</c>
  </row>
  <row>
    <b>5</b>
    <a>2</a>
    <c>8</c>
  </row>
  <row>
    <a>2</a>
    <c>8</c>
    <b>6</b>
  </row>
</root>
```

Is there an easy way to assert that the XML document is sorted on element B in XMLUnit

*Edit:* I have an odd problem with a piece of software that I can not change where the value of the XML tags in any given node needs to be in a specific order. I'd like it for my test harness to enforce this set of rules before any other validation.

Comment: I can't think of any (but then again, I don't know XmlUnit et al). Why do you want to do this? Is this the output of some method to be tested? Can you refactor the code to produce output in a more testable format?

Comment: @Peter, I'm dealing with some legacy software where the XML needs to be in a quirky format. I'd like to make sure my xml output always obeys those quirky rules.

Comment: Good Question (+1). See my answer for a very simple solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use the value of the following simple XPath 1.0 expression**:

**`not(//b[. > following::b])`**

Comment: This is almost what I wanted. I got my solution after looking at this.  Thanks!

Comment: Hey sal, what IS your solution?

Comment: @belwood: @sal says that he put this XPath expression in his code -- probably the real column names were different. If you have the same problem, this answer should get you going.

Answer (score 1):

You can build an assertion around an XPath selection.

Probably the simplest way would be to use the XPath expression `/root/row/b`, request the `NODESET` result type, then copy the text from each result node into a `List` structure. You can assert that the text in that list is equal to an "expected" list created with the `Arrays.asList()` method (I'm assuming you're using Java).

Comment: This was what I was doing and I wasn't happy with it. For starters, there was too much code that was specific to a particular test and more code that might have to change as my code changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you can execute XQuery, then the XQuery assertion:

```
every $i in (1 to count ($x/row) - 1)
satisfies 
   let $j :=  $i + 1   
   return number($x/row[$i]/b) <= number($x/row[$j]/b)
```

where $x is the document, is true if the rows are in ascending order of b, false otherwise

Comment: I'm too junior to comment on Dimitre's neat answer but shouldn't it be
not($x//b[number(.) > following::b/number(.)]) for this numeric data 
and isnt this O N^2 since every b is compared with all the following b's?